# How to ignore specific file extension in specific folder in Visual Studio Code

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code, appsettings

I'd like to hide all files with extension `.ekv` in directory `a/b` using setting `Files:Exclude` I've tried `**a/b/*.ekv`, but this doesn't work. Could anybody help?
[Setting in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPbXW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the slash before `a` is missing, maybe trying `**/a/b/*.ekv` ?
Here is a [tool](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2F%2A%2A%2F%2A.js&matches=false&tests=%2F%2F%20This%20will%20match%20as%20it%20ends%20with%20%27.js%27&tests=%2Fhello%2Fworld.js&tests=%2F%2F%20This%20won%27t%20match%21&tests=%2Ftest%2Fsome%2Fglobs) that I use for trying glob patterns

Comment: This still doesn't work. For example, I've a file in PATH `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo/cfg/cpu_level_0_pc_ss.ekv` the Glob Tool says that `**/csgo/cfg/*.ekv` should match, but it doesn't. I don't know if this has any influence, but I have opened only `cfg` directory in VScode.

Comment: @kamack38 I would suggest simply `**/*.ekv` but if you are always accessing the folder with path `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/`, maybe `./csgo/cfg/*.ekv` should work. `./csgo` means the `csgo` folder in the top level of the VScode workspace.

Comment: `"**/a/b/*.ekv": true`  works, I tested it.  You are setting it to `true`? Not `false`.